# Is it possible to put input box over existing google map using HTML?

Tags: html

I have a Google fusion table map URL address.

```
https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?q=select+col4+from+1on3uHh7-gAK9Ji0FLuxmXaB41-yMCgOksLdLIzo+where+col1+contains+ignoring+case+%27squash%27&viz=MAP&h=false&lat=50.02742532618674&lng=14.533565155029219&t=1&z=11&l=col4&y=2&tmplt=2&hml=GEOCODABLE
```

The question is....
Is it possible to create local html file, that opens mentioned URL and puts over opened page (map) input box?

I know that it is possible when I use javascript to create that map but I am not sure if it is possible with pre-created map (web page).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a mistake...but you put div#panel inside "a", so any click forward the user to google maps (as the link specified).

Aside this problem your code should works...